# Certbot is killing my apache server

Tags: apache2, certbot

So once in a while I receive an email about apache being unreachable. I mean it actively rejects connections (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED for Chrome).

```
systemctl status apache2
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2020-06-09 14:36:58 CEST; 8min ago
  Process: 2533 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4325 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20597 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 20603 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Syslog

```
Jun  9 14:36:01 f CRON[2494]: (www-data) CMD (php /var/www/avg.php)
Jun  9 14:36:57 f systemd[1]: Starting Certbot...
Jun  9 14:36:58 f apachectl[2533]: httpd (no pid file) not running
Jun  9 14:37:01 f CRON[2544]: (www-data) CMD (php /var/www/avg.php)
Jun  9 14:37:25 f systemd[1]: Started Certbot.
Jun  9 14:37:25 f systemd[1]: certbot.timer: Adding 2h 47min 35.570277s random time.
Jun  9 14:37:25 f systemd[1]: certbot.timer: Adding 1h 45min 16.226705s random time.
```

The last second apache were running and logging was at 09/Jun/2020:14:36:02 (it is server which receives a bunch of requests from cron from other servers once a minute, so it is totally cool that there was no log entry during the last minute).

I tried upgrading certbot but it seems it is in the last possible version.

```
certbot is already the newest version (0.28.0-1~deb9u2).
python-certbot-apache is already the newest version (0.28.0-1~deb9u1).
```

This didn't happen for the first time and I didn't find much online. 
What are the next steps I could do to find the caveat?

EDIT: /var/log/letsencrypt.log

```
2020-06-09 14:36:58,199:INFO:certbot.hooks:Running pre-hook command: apachectl -k stop
2020-06-09 14:36:58,250:INFO:certbot.main:Renewing an existing certificate
```

at the end

```
2020-06-09 14:37:25,395:DEBUG:certbot.renewal:no renewal failures
2020-06-09 14:37:25,395:INFO:certbot.hooks:Running post-hook command: apachectl -k start
```

Is there a way to configure certbot not using port 80 but rather some else so I don't need my apache to stop during renewal (and in the worst time possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Рамиль Матрасов mentioned, you have configured Certbot to run its own webserver i.e. in the [standalone](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#standalone) plugin, while you should have been using the [webroot](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#webroot) plugin, instead. Your configuration causes Certbot to stop Apache so that it can bind to port `80`. Also, the DNS-01 challenge suggested by Henrik Pingel seems unnecessarily complicated for your use case.

> **Webroot**
>
> If you’re running a local webserver for which you have the ability to
>   modify the content being served, and you’d prefer not to stop the
>   webserver during the certificate issuance process, you can use the
>   webroot plugin to obtain a certificate by including certonly and
>   `--webroot` on the command line. In addition, you’ll need to specify `--webroot-path` or `-w` with the top-level directory (“web root”) containing the files served by your webserver.

However, showing what you *should have done* doesn't really help you solving the current problem: you can also **change the current settings** by modifying the configuration files in `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal`. E.g. in `example.com.conf` you might currently have:

```
[renewalparams]
authenticator = standalone
webroot_path = /home/letsencrypt,
[[webroot_map]]
example.com = /home/letsencrypt
www.example.com = /home/letsencrypt
```

Replace the `authenticator = standalone` with `authenticator = webroot` for every configuration file and also check that the `webroot_path` or maps match the ones you have in your Apache `<VirtualHost>`s, e.g.

```
[renewalparams]
authenticator = webroot
[[webroot_map]]
example.com = /var/www/example.com
www.example.com = /var/www/example.com
```

You can test your new configuration with `certbot renew --dry-run`.

Comment: Is there a way to do a wildcard without a DNS challenge? Haha you perfectly answered the question I just thought about from reading the other guy's answer :-)

Comment: DNS-01 challenge is required for wildcard certificates. That's an inevitable security decision: you wouldn't want just any `webhosting.example.com` to be able to get certificates for your entire domain.

Answer (score 2):

you have misconfigured certbot, certbot can use apache as web server to handle AMCE-challenge.. and you configured it to use his own embedded web server.
you should do like this:

```
./certbot-auto certonly --webroot -d host.example.com --webroot-path /var/www/html
```

when you done it once, then just crontab this:

```
certbot-auto renew
```

this config will use /var/www/html to create .well-known dir with challenge and use your apache.

Comment: How do I do this in the actual configuration for these pages? Will it overwrite the old config after I run this command?

Answer (score 1):

Configure [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/challenges.html) to use [DNS-01](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#dns-01-challenge) challenge instead of `HTTP-01` challenge.

Comment: How can that work considering you have to change a DNS record for that, don't you?

Comment: That method works by adding a TXT record to DNS. There is no need to change the A record. However in this case I would recommend you to debug and fix the issues with certbot and stick with http-01. In any way it is an option if your dns provider is supported by certbot. The list of supported dns providers is listed in the linked documentation.

Comment: But that TXT record have to change every few months when renewing.

Comment: That is supposed to be done by certbot. No matter which challenge method used it is not the worst idea to configure a cron job for certbot.